# Install Linux on existing multiboot system without messing up drive letters

Tags: windows-7, linux, windows-xp, multi-boot

I've finally gotten my multi-boot development system (WinXP, Win7x86, Win7x64) booting properly so that no matter which OS boots, it boots as if OS is C: and there is a D: for scratch / sharing between OS's.

I now want to add Linux to the mix but I don't want to mess up the fragile grasp the Microsoft OS's have on their drive letter identity being C: no matter what. (In case you're wondering, to get them all to recognize themselves as C: you have to install WinXP first, then Win7x86 then Win7x64.)

I don't have another terabyte drive to image this to in case I mess it up so I don't want to guess at the proper procedure.

Can I simply install Linux (Mint 15 Cinnamon is what I'm going with) and let Grub take over managing multiboot? If the Microsoft OS's don't retain their drive letters as C: when booting, I have to start over.

Comment: I **suspect** that the drive order will not change because you are installing volumes with a filesystem which neither of the three windows OS's recognise per default. However I completely agree with "a fragile grasp on drive letters" and I would always make a backup before testing.  (Using ghost or similar software which compresses the image and ignores free space).

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have another terabyte drive to image this to...

Comment: I know. This is why I wrote 'software which compresses the image'. The image might still be big, but depending on how full the disk is it will be significantly less than a terabyte.

Answer (score 1):

Windows won't change which drive it identifies as C: after it is installed.  Other partitions that it has seen before and assigned a letter won't change unless you change them in the disk management utility.

Comment: So if I shrink existing partitions to add the 3 Linux will want, that won't throw Windows off? It should just assign new letters to the newly visible (but non-accessible to Microsoft OS's) partitions?

Comment: @AppFzx, yes, and if the Linux partitions are created correctly it won't even assign them a drive letter at all.

Comment: So far I'm on the third attempt. (I did use Clonezilla to back it all up) If this method doesn't work, I'll post partition tables and things I've tried.